# Discord.JS Embed Command Help Needed

Tags: discord.js

I need help with the following:

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {

  if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
    const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split("|");
    // message.channel.send(args);
    const embed = function(title, description, footer) {
      return new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(title)
        .setDescription(description)
        .setFooter(footer)
    }
    
    if (args[0] === "embed") {
    const sendEmbed = embed(args[1], args[2], args[3]);
    message.channel.send(sendEmbed);
  };   } });
```

I want to make a command where if you type in `-embed <title>|<description>|<footer>` you would get an embed with those elements.

Comment: What's the issue? You don't state what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

What I did for this with my bot is the following:

```js
// split into each section, you can change '/' to be whatever you want
const embedInfo = args.join(' ').split('/');
// create the embed
const embed = new MessageEmbed();
// the first part of the message, before the /
embed.setTitle(embedInfo[0]);
// the second part of the message, after the /
embed.setDescription(embedInfo[1]);
// send it!
message.channel.send(embed);
```

This means if the message is "This is a title / this is a description", then the title will be "This is a title". and the description will be "this is a description". Keep in mind you should filter the input as if there are > 256 characters in the title you will get an error.